# how to get a sorted array out of Map.keys()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
const map1 = new Map();

map1.set('0', 'foo');
map1.set(1, 'bar');

const iterator1 = map1.keys().sort();//error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys) returns an *iterator*, not an array. Iterators don't have `Array.prototype.sort` or an equivalent. You can make an array from it, though, and sort that:

```
const result = [...map1.keys()].sort();
```

or

```
const result = Array.from(map1.keys()).sort();
```